# Skolemization problem:∀x∃y∀z∃u (A(x,y,z,u) v B(y,u))

Tags: first-order-logic

Everything in the title but an explanation would be nice beside an answer! I don't really know if I should use constants or functions.

Comment: In this case, only functions. You introduce constants for any initial existential quantifiers, and here there are none. As in @Mauro's answer, you can be slick and consider constants to be zero-place functions — a thing which (when applied to no arguments) designates an individual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Skolemization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form) is performed by replacing every existentially quantified variable $y$ with a term $f(x_i)$ whose function symbol $f$ is new.

If the formula is in prenex normal form, the variables $x_i$ of this term are the variable universally quantified whose quantifiers precede that of $y$.

The function $f$ introduced in this process is called a *Skolem function* (or *Skolem constant* if it is of zero arity, i.e. if the existential quantifier to be removed is **not** preceded by any universal quantifier).

Thus, in order to "skolemize" :

> $∀x∃y∀z∃u \ldots$

we need a 1st skolem function $f(x)$ for the $∃y$ existential quantifier (1-arity, because $∃y$ is preceded by $∀x$) and a 2nd one $g(x,z)$ for the $∃u$ existential quantifier (2-arity, because $∃u$ is preceded by $∀x$ and $∀z$).